# Loading a UIImage in WatchKit from a different Bundle

Tags: uiimage, watchkit, wkinterfaceimage

My app is currently structured to use dynamic library to enable code reuse. I have images stored within my dynamic library so they can easily be shared between different app targets. This works fine in iOS because I can use the `UIImage(named:, in:, compatibleWith:)` initializer to load the image from my dynamic library. However, this initializer doesn't seem to be available on watchOS. Is there any other method of loading images from a dynamic library (with a different bundle) on watchOS. By the way, the image is stored within an Asset Catalog.

Answer (score 2):

The workaround I discovered was to use the `Bundle`'s `resourceURL` to get the root directory of the `Bundle`'s resource folder and then loading the images manually from the filesystem using `Data(contentsOf:)` and `UIImage(data:)`.  This does not seem to work with Asset Catalogs though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sharing a piece of code that will load image from bundle and it is compatible with OSX, watchOS and iOS. if you only want the solution for watchOS only then take `#elseif os(watchOS)` part out

```
#if os(OSX)
    import AppKit
    public typealias Image = NSImage
#elseif os(watchOS)
    import WatchKit
    public typealias Image = UIImage
#else
    import UIKit
    public typealias Image = UIImage
#endif

public extension String
{
    func image(in bundle: Bundle? = Bundle.main) -> Image?
    {
        #if os(OSX)
            guard let img = bundle?.image(forResource: self) else {
                return nil
            }
        #elseif os(watchOS)
            guard let resource = bundle?.resourceURL, let img = try? Image(data: Data(contentsOf: resource)) else {
                return nil
            }
        #else
            guard let img = Image(named: self, in: bundle, compatibleWith: nil) else {
                return nil
            }
        #endif

        return img
    }
}
```